# Parse XML Sitemap with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a sitemap like this: http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml which is structured like this:

```
<sitemapindex>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_static_0.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-07</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_alpha_0.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-07</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
...
```

And I want to extract data from it. First of all I need to count how many `<sitemap>` are in the xml and then for each of them, extract the `<loc>` and `<lastmod>` data. Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

I've seen other questions like this but all of them extract for example every `<loc>` element inside the xml, I need to extract data individually from each element.

I've tried to use `lxml` with this code:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

u = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml')
doc = etree.parse(u)

element_list = doc.findall('sitemap')

for element in element_list:
    url = store.findtext('loc')
    print url
```

but `element_list` is empty.

Comment: A good StackOverflow question shows what you've tried already, and how it's failing. (I wholeheartedly agree with Anand that `lxml` is the right tool for the job; if you try it and have trouble, *then* you'll have cause to ask a question here).

Comment: Could also use https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html , no?

Comment: @tandy, sure -- it's built-in, but on the other hand, doesn't have real XPath. I tend to ignore it for the latter reason.

Comment: lxml doesn't work, anybody can help me understanding why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I chose to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) libraries. I created a dictionary where the key is the url and the value is the last modified date.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

xml_dict = {}

r = requests.get("http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml")
xml = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
sitemap_tags = soup.find_all("sitemap")

print(f"The number of sitemaps are {len(sitemapTags)}")

for sitemap in sitemap_tags:
    xml_dict[sitemap.findNext("loc").text] = sitemap.findNext("lastmod").text

print(xml_dict)
```

Or with [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

xml_dict = {}

r = requests.get("http://www.site.co.uk/sitemap.xml")
root = etree.fromstring(r.content)
print(f"The number of sitemap tags are {len(root)}")
for sitemap in root:
    children = sitemap.getchildren()
    xml_dict[children[0].text] = children[1].text
print(xml_dict)
```

Comment: An HTML parser for XML? I mean, it works, but it's going to be needlessly permissive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Updated my answer...I never used lxml before so it took me a little bit

Comment: BeautifulSoup says that since is not specified it uses lxml parser by default, then changing `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')` works perfect!

Comment: @Hyperion it probably changed since you wrote that command because as of today the default parser used by BeautifulSoup is `html.parser`.

Answer (score 7):

Using Python 3, requests, Pandas and list comprehension:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict

url = "https://www.gov.uk/sitemap.xml"
res = requests.get(url)
raw = xmltodict.parse(res.text)

data = [[r["loc"], r["lastmod"]] for r in raw["sitemapindex"]["sitemap"]]
print("Number of sitemaps:", len(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["links", "lastmod"])
```

Output:

```
    links                                       lastmod
0   https://www.gov.uk/sitemaps/sitemap_1.xml   2018-11-06T01:10:02+00:00
1   https://www.gov.uk/sitemaps/sitemap_2.xml   2018-11-06T01:10:02+00:00
2   https://www.gov.uk/sitemaps/sitemap_3.xml   2018-11-06T01:10:02+00:00
3   https://www.gov.uk/sitemaps/sitemap_4.xml   2018-11-06T01:10:02+00:00
4   https://www.gov.uk/sitemaps/sitemap_5.xml   2018-11-06T01:10:02+00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

this function will extract all urls from xml

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_urls_of_xml(xml_url):
    r = requests.get(xml_url)
    xml = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

    links_arr = []
    for link in soup.findAll('loc'):
        linkstr = link.getText('', True)
        links_arr.append(linkstr)

    return links_arr



links_data_arr = get_urls_of_xml("https://www.gov.uk/sitemap.xml")
print(links_data_arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here using `BeautifulSoup` to get `sitemap` count and extract text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
 <sitemap>
    <loc>
    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_static_0.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-07</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>
    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_alpha_0.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-07</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
"""

soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
sitemap_count = len(soup.find_all('sitemap'))
print("sitemap count: %d" % sitemap)
print(soup.get_text())
```

Output:

```
sitemap count: 2

    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_static_0.xml

2015-07-07

    http://www.site.co.uk/drag_it/dragitsitemap_alpha_0.xml

2015-07-07
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `advertools` which has a special function for [parsing XML sitemaps](https://advertools.readthedocs.io/en/master/advertools.sitemaps.html). It also can parse zipped sitemaps by default (.xml.gz).
In case you have a sitemap index file, it also recursively gets them all into one DataFrame.

```py
import advertools as adv

economist =  adv.sitemap_to_df('https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml')
economist.head()
```

|  | loc | lastmod | changefreq | priority | sitemap | etag | sitemap_last_modified | sitemap_size_mb | download_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://www.economist.com/printedition/2022-01-22 | 2022-01-20 15:57:17+00:00 | daily | 0.6 | https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml | e2637d17284eefef7d1eafb9ef4ebe3a | 2022-01-22 04:00:54+00:00 | 0.0865097 | 2022-01-23 00:01:41.026416+00:00 |
| 1 | https://www.economist.com/the-world-this-week/2022/01/22/kals-cartoon | 2022-01-20 16:53:34+00:00 | daily | 0.6 | https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml | e2637d17284eefef7d1eafb9ef4ebe3a | 2022-01-22 04:00:54+00:00 | 0.0865097 | 2022-01-23 00:01:41.026416+00:00 |
| 2 | https://www.economist.com/united-states/2022/01/22/a-new-barbie-doll-commemorates-a-19th-century-suffragist | 2022-01-20 16:10:36+00:00 | daily | 0.6 | https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml | e2637d17284eefef7d1eafb9ef4ebe3a | 2022-01-22 04:00:54+00:00 | 0.0865097 | 2022-01-23 00:01:41.026416+00:00 |
| 3 | https://www.economist.com/britain/2022/01/22/tory-mps-love-to-hate-the-bbc-but-tory-voters-love-to-watch-it | 2022-01-20 17:09:59+00:00 | daily | 0.6 | https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml | e2637d17284eefef7d1eafb9ef4ebe3a | 2022-01-22 04:00:54+00:00 | 0.0865097 | 2022-01-23 00:01:41.026416+00:00 |
| 4 | https://www.economist.com/china/2022/01/22/the-communist-party-revisits-its-egalitarian-roots | 2022-01-20 16:48:14+00:00 | daily | 0.6 | https://www.economist.com/sitemap-2022-Q1.xml | e2637d17284eefef7d1eafb9ef4ebe3a | 2022-01-22 04:00:54+00:00 | 0.0865097 | 2022-01-23 00:01:41.026416+00:00 |

Comment: A bit overkilling to use advertools just for this....

Comment: Why? 

It's a single line of code. It works recursively by default. Handles zipped and regular sitemaps. Also includes other tags and info, like lastmod, etag, sitemap size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good library: https://github.com/mediacloud/ultimate-sitemap-parser.

Website sitemap parser for Python 3.5+.

Installation:

```
pip install ultimate-sitemap-parser
```

Example of extracting all pages of the site nytimes.com from sitemaps:

```
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage("https://www.nytimes.com/")
for page in tree.all_pages():
    print(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using proper libs with modern Python3: `requests` and `lxml`, even with encoding `utf8` from the `XML` declaration:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from pprint import pprint

session = requests.session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

res = session.get('https://example.org/sitemap-xml', headers=headers)
xml_bytes = res.text.encode('utf-8')

# Parse the XML bytes
root = etree.fromstring(xml_bytes)

# Define the namespace
ns = {'sitemap': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'}

urls = root.xpath('//sitemap:url[./sitemap:loc[contains(., "/en-us/")]]', namespaces=ns)

# List comprehension
urls = [u.xpath('./sitemap:loc/text()', namespaces=ns)[0] for u in urls]

pprint(urls)
```

Answer (score -1):

i just had the quest today. I used requests and re (regular expressions)
import requests
import re

```
sitemap_url = "https://www.gov.uk/sitemap.xml"
#if you need to send some headers
headers = {'user-agent': 'myApp'}
response = requests.get(sitemap_url,headers = headers)
xml = response.text

list_of_urls = []

for address in re.findall(r"https://.*(?=/</)", xml):
    list_of_urls.append(address+'/')#i add trailing slash, you might want to skip it
```

Comment: This reminds me of this famous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/735926